# How to make two WIR 1186 RF transceivers communicate over serial communication?

Tags: serial, rf

I want to have two RF transceivers communicate, one as transmitter and one as a receiver, for longer distances. For that I'm using WIR 1186 RF modules with Arduino.

Pin connections are as below:

- Arduino :5v,gnd,RX,TX,2,3
- WIR1186 :VCC,gnd,Tx,Rx,prg,cts

But Arduino is not serially communicating with the WIR1186 module.

Below is the code:

```
char ch;
int prog = 2;
int cts = 3;
int stat;
unsigned int output;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(prog, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(prog, LOW);
  stat = digitalRead(prog);
  Serial.println(stat);  
  Serial.write("B=9600\r\n");
  output = Serial.read();
  Serial.println(output); 
  digitalWrite(cts, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.write('a');
  delay(1000);
}
```

[Here is the datasheet of WIR1186](http://robokits.download/datasheets/WIR-1186_RobokitsIndia.pdf)

Please help me out with this.

Comment: `digitalWrite(cts, HIGH);` --- Are you sure about that?

Comment: yes,clear to send should be high when we are sending

Comment: Err... have you *read* the datasheet?

Comment: yes i referred that and i have downloaded WIR library from GIthub, based on the header file function i have given cts High, Before that the commands in setup are also not sending to WIR module

Comment: Is your WIR-1186 on some kind of carrier board with voltage regulator and logic level translation?

Answer (score 1):

If you use pin 2 and 3 for serial communication you have to use [SoftSerial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial), because Serial is hardwired to pin 0 and 1.

Comment: pin 2 and 3 of arduino has connected to prog and cts pins of WIR module

Answer (score 1):

Two things are wrong:

1. You aren't setting PROG to HIGH to enable transmit mode - you are stuck in programming mode.
2. CTS is an *output from the module to an input on the Arduino*. You don't set it high - you look to see what level it is to see if it is safe to send more data.

To quote from the datasheet you link to:

> The WIR-1186 offers data flow control hardware to allow for zero data over-run and loss when sending large
> files and data packets. The internal data buffer on the WIR-1186 module is 128bytes. When the data terminal<sup>1</sup>
> sends a large file for wireless transmission the module<sup>2</sup> will except 128bytes and then set the CTS pin LOW to
> alert the data terminal to wait for the CTS to back HIGH before sending more data over UART.

(footnotes mine)

Also you *cannot* use pins 0 and 1 for serial if you are at the same time using them for USB debugging. You will either have to move to another pair of pins and use `SoftwareSerial`, or invest in a better Arduino with more than one UART.

Another thing of importance: If your WIR-1186 isn't on some kind of carrier board with voltage regulator and logic level translation it's safe to say that you have killed it. Well done.

> ## Warnings
>
> - **The maximum allowable voltage on any of the interface pins with respect to GND is 3.6V**
> - **The maximum input voltage VCC with respect to GND is 3.6V**
> - The baud rate setting in configure mode is fixed 9600bps
> - Do not leave the UART_TX input pin of the module open. The module will send junk data on thewireless channel. It must be pulled up to VCC if not used.

---

<sup>1</sup> Arduino
<sup>2</sup> WIR-1186

Comment: but it is not entering into command mode also ,when i send a command in setup as in the program it is not giving any response

Comment: Your program isn't looking for a response. It's looking to see if there's a single character in the RX buffer at the moment you send the command. Learn the basics of serial before trying to use it. https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/

Comment: no response is getting, Serial.read() is printing -1